# Can MySql load from XML directly

Tags: mysql, xml

I am aware of the batch LOAD XML technique e.g. [Load XML Update Table--MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924973/load-xml-update-table-mysql)

Can MySql insert/replace rows directly from xml. I'd like to pass an XML string to MySQL.

Something like replace into user XML VALUES  maybe even using as to map the tags to the column names??

The primary thing is that I dont want to parse the XML in my code, I'd like MySql to handle this. I dont have a file, I have the XML as a string.

I have looked and found there are some XML Functions:
[12.11. XML Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/xml-functions.html)

The XML functions can do XPath, but I think this is a little fiddly as I have a 1:1 mapping from the XML to the table structure so I'd hjst like to be able to say hey MySql, insert the values in the xml string in to the table.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, No.

What your looking for is an XML storage engine for MySQL. There has never been one created officially, and i have never seen a third party one either (but feel free to google).

If you really want to achieve this, then the closest you would get is to look for an alternative (R)DMS, but then that might not support the type of queries you wish to perform, may require a bit of a learning curve, would no doubt require you are using a server with superuser access, and potentially mean re-factoring a lot of your code.

Comment: I did expect that this would be the case as I couldnt find a way. Having found the LOAD XML process I thought there might just be something I had missed. Thanks for the reply.